# Combined regex in WinScp to Download files with specific string in it

Tags: regex, cmd, winscp

I have many files in a directory and the files are named like below,

```
EE_SuccessfulTransfer_jobID_HOMEAPPREMIND01X_BT_<date>_SUCCESS_XFER.csv
EE_SuccessfulTransfer_jobID_HOMEAPPREMIND03X_BT_<date>_SUCCESS_XFER.csv
EEHOMEAPPREMIND01X _<date>_EXPORT.csv
EEHOMEAPPREMIND03X _<date>_EXPORT.csv
EE_SuccessfulTransfer_jobID_HOMEAPPREMIND03X_BT_<date>_SUCCESS_XFER.csv
EEHOMEAPPCALLBACK_BT_<Date>_SUCCESS_XFER_EXPORT.csv
```

Where JobID is dynamic. (It can be anything)

**I want to download 2 files:**

```
EE_SuccessfulTransfer_jobID_HOMEAPPREMIND01X_BT_<date>_SUCCESS_XFER.csv
```

**And**

```
EEHOMEAPPREMIND01X _<date>_EXPORT.csv
```

I am Using **WinScp command prompt** to download the files.

**The command used is :**

```
 get [EEHOMEAPPREMIND01X+_|EE+_SuccessfulTransfer+_*+_HOMEAPPREMIND01X]*.csv
```

But it is downloading all the files from the directory.

Comment: That doesn't look like regex...

Comment: @Biffen - Any solution to it please? I am new to regex.

Comment: ...As I thought, WinSCP [uses *wildcards*](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/file_mask), not regex. So RT*M. Without testing it I'd say something like `get EE_SuccessfulTransfer_*_HOMEAPPREMIND01X_BT_*_SUCCESS_XFER.csv EEHOMEAPPREMIND01X _*_EXPORT.csv` should work.

Comment: The reason your command downloads all the files is that it matches all files that begin with one of `|_*+01aAcDeEfHIlMnNOPrRsSTuX` (which is what `[EEHOMEAPPREMIND01X+_|EE+_SuccessfulTransfer+_*+_HOMEAPPREMIND01X]` means) followed by any number of any characters (`*`) followed by `.csv`.

Comment: @Biffen - I am getting an error when I tried ur command.

winscp> get EE_SuccessfulTransfer_*_HOMEAPPREMIND01X_BT_*_SUCCESS_XFER.csv EEHOM
EAPPREMIND01X _*_EXPORT.csv
Can't get attributes of file 'EEHOMEAPPREMIND01X'.
No such file or directory.
Error code: 2
Error message from server (en): File not found

Comment: Oh, it seems there's a space in there (that I missed). Are there spaces in the file names? If so it needs escaped in the command. If not just adjust the command accordingly.

Comment: I had to add .\ at the end of the command, as a last parameter though.